# Why do I keep getting an error that array indices must be positive?

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing

It says the index in position 1 of the diff function must be a positive integer or a logical value which is it so why am I getting this error? I'm trying to implement the basic Euler method in MATLAB

```
y=zeros(1,6);
h=0;
x(1)= 0;
y(1)= 0;
i=1;
diff(y,x)= x+y
    while h<=1
    y(i+1)=y(i) + h*f(x(i))
    h=h+0.2;
    i=i+1;
    end
```

Edit: Changed it to the code below but it still raises the same error in the line `y(i+1)=`...

```
y=zeros(1,6);
x=zeros(1,6);
h=0;
i=1;
g=x+y;
    while h<=1
    y(i+1)=y(i) + h*g(x(i),y(i));
    h=h+0.2;
    i=i+1;
    end
```

Comment: This doesn't look like a proper MATLAB program. What are `x`? `y`? `f`? What is `diff`? Are you trying to define it?

Comment: I was trying to write that dy/dx is equal to x+y but I think it won't work so I just changed it right now to a random variable instead. I changed the code about a bit but I'm still getting the same error but now for the line that starts with y(i+1). I've edited the post to show the new code.

Comment: Do you expect `f` and `g` to be functions? They're not. Unless you define them as functions, they're variables and `x(i)` is an index into that variable (array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach:** I would recommend defining an [anonymous function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html)

```
diffh =@(x,y) x + y;             % define this prior to use
```

to use later inside the loop. 
Then changing one line

```
y(ii+1)=y(ii) + h*diffh(x(ii),y(ii));
```

should work. I've added the "h" to the end as a convention to remind me this is an anonymous function (see note at end).

```
% MATLAB R2019a
y = zeros(1,6);
x = zeros(1,6);
h=0;
ii=1;
diffh =@(x,y) x + y;
while h <= 1
    y(ii+1)=y(ii) + h*diffh(x(ii),y(ii));
    x(ii+1) = x(ii)+h;
    h=h+0.2;
    ii=ii+1;
end
```

**Side note:** I've also changed the index `i` to `ii` by convention (though MATLAB doesn't require this). Unless you overwrite their values, both `i` and `j` default as the  `sqrt(-1)`. You can absolutely use them as indices without issue (provided you don't later need complex or imaginary numbers). To ensure this never becomes an issue, many people just use `ii` and `jj` as a convention to preserve the default values.

---

Note that [`diff`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) is a MATLAB function itself.

Comment: Tried this but now I'm getting a different error on the line y(ii+1) of "index exceeds the number of array elements". I don't get why it's returning that since it should automatically creating a new element in the array to assign the value to, should it not?

Comment: @user552217 What's your final expected output for `y`? Code runs for me without errors (see full code posted for clarify). Did you `clear h ii x y` before re-running?

Comment: I just copied and pasted your code ( and I cleared the workspace) and the code runs but it just gives back y= [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ]. Only the first two elements should be 0 (initial y was given as 0 and 2nd y returns as 0) but element 3 should be 0.04, element 4 0.128 then 0.2736 and then 0.48832 for the final element. I've verified this by hand and my lecture notes also have that as the answer. Any idea why your code doesn't give the right answer?

Comment: Then there's a logical error in the code for sure!   Gotta run but will check this later.  I'll have to look at Euler's method to see the mistake.

Comment: @user552217 Why would it be `0.04`? `0 + 0.2*0` is still `0`. Trace your code. `y` is never changed.

Comment: @beaker Ah, nice catch. Forgot to mention that x has to be incremented by h every loop so x0 is 0, x1 is 0.2 and x2 is 0.4 until it reaches 1. I forgot to include that so that's why the Agent's code wasn't working. Tried now with x incremented and it works. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Using `i` as an index is mostly not a good idea in Matlab, because `i` is also imaginary number. Perhaps another name could solve the problem.

Comment: Tried with a different variable but still didn't work :/

Comment: MATLAB can use `i` just fine as an index (though it isn't preferred). This won't cause an error (this is easily verified with a trivial loop).